# Convrsion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

After a pause I decided to continue with Android apps and decided to build my old app. So when I'm trying to export signed application in Eclipse, I got folloing error:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:317)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:313)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:238)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:825)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:274)
... 4 more
```

Sometimes I get this error with
`Caused by: Proguard Error 1 Output: Note: there were 10 duplicate class definitions.` (all duplicates in my package, not in libraries).

`Poject build target 19
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
ADT the latest version`

Proguard.cfg

```
`-optimizationpasses 7
-allowaccessmodification
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-repackageclasses 'com.mypackage'

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepattributes *Annotation* 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
-keep public class com.slidingmenu.lib.** {*;}
-keep public class com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; } 
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; } 
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; } 
-keep class roboguice.** { *; } 

# Action bar sherlock 
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 

# Remove's all references to Log.v and Log.d 
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

I've already tried all advices (among them reinstalling environment), but it's still not working.

It would be great if somebody can help me.

Comment: Clean All Project present in the eclipse and then restart eclipse

if you are using windows PC then open Task manager and adb.exe end that process and force full stop all the adb processes.

Then again open your eclipse and then try again...
OR if this all stuff doesn't work then update your adt with latest
ADT 23.0.2

Download from official website Now Eclipse become Eclipse Juno and symbol also changed.

Comment: @BabulPatel The first part of your advice worked! Please, write it as the answer, I'll check it as the best. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean All Project present in the eclipse and then restart eclipse if you are using windows PC then open Task manager and adb.exe end that process and force full stop all the adb processes. Then again open your eclipse and then try again... OR if this all stuff doesn't work then update your adt with latest ADT 23.0.2 Download from official website Now Eclipse become Eclipse Juno and symbol also changed.